# Couldn't find any versions for "cra-template-typescript" that matches "latest" in our cache

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, yarnpkg, npx

Trying to follow this guide: [How to Build a Simple React app With Express API](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-build-a-simple-react-app-with-express-api-b4ab3d16f06d) but when running

```
npx create-react-app react-express-app --template typescript
```

I get this output:

```
npx: installed 98 in 12.964s

Creating a new React app in /home/aioobe/projects/daily-challenge-5/react-express-app.

error Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt'
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template-typescript...

You appear to be offline.
Falling back to the local Yarn cache.

yarn add v1.22.4
error Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt'
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find any versions for "cra-template-typescript" that matches "latest" in our cache (possible versions are ""). This is usually caused by a missing entry in the lockfile, running Yarn without the --offline flag may help fix this issue.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact --offline react react-dom react-scripts cra-template-typescript --cwd /home/aioobe/projects/daily-challenge-5/react-express-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting react-express-app/ from /home/aioobe/projects/daily-challenge-5
Done.
```

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on here?

Comment: `You appear to be offline`, falling back to cache. Perhaps .. reinstall cra?

Comment: Thank you @Xorifelse, that was more or less precisely it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some more googling and someone suggested it was a network issue, so i fiddled with my VPN and it finally worked.

So, if you run into this, check that you have proper network connection working.